# Dropdown onchange isn't fired

Tags: angular

I need help with this `select`, it's populated with db and I need to get the item selected when change the item.

```html
<select class="custom-select col-md-12" id="operation" name="operation" formControlName="operation">
  <option *ngFor="let operation of operations" [ngValue]="operation.id" (ngModelChange)="show(operation)">{{ operation.value}}</option>
</select>
```

```
show(value){
   ...
}
```

I already tried with `(change)` and `[(ngModel)]` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event should be in `<select>` tag:

```html
<select class="custom-select col-md-12" id="operation"
(ngModelChange)="show($event)" name="operation" formControlName="operation">
  <option *ngFor="let operation of operations" [ngValue]="operation.id" \>
  {{ operation.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is it, thank you very much and sorry for the lack of attention

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding formcontrolName then you no need bind the change event in html. You can subscribe the change event in ts itself. But if you want to bind the change event via html then remove the formcontrolName binding and bind change event in html.

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  operations = [{ id: 1, value: 'test' }, { id: 2, value: 'test2' }, { id: 3, value: 'test3' }];

  show(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select col-md-12" id="operation" name="operation" (change)="show($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let operation of operations" [value]="operation.id" >{{ operation.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Example:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This is it, thank you very much and sorry for the lack of attention